# Prove a "weaker alternative" of Fourier inverse transform of a continuous $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Given a continuous function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and a function $g$ such that both $g$ and $\hat{g}$ are in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, $\int_\mathbb{R}g(x)dx = 1$. The first part of the problem is to prove $\hat{g}(\delta\xi) \rightarrow1$ as $\delta \rightarrow 0$ for any $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$, which I have done. Then the second part is to prove

$$f(x) = \lim_{\delta\rightarrow0}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{i2\pi\xi x}\hat{g}(\delta\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)d\xi$$

I have tried to derive the right hand side of the above eq. to the form of $(g*f)(x) = \int_\mathbb{R}g(x-t)f(t)dt$. But I have failed, and have no clue right now.

Edit: After going back to the lecture note, I believe I've found the right tool. From $g$ we can construct an approximation identity $K_n(x) = ng(nx)$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have $f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(K_n*f)(x)$. Thus we only need to prove the right hand side of eq. is nothing but the convolution of $K_n$ and $f$.

Thanks for the comment!

Edit again: I decide to derive from the convolution. Let $K_n(x) = ng(nx)$ be a sequence of functions, then $\{K_n\}$ is an approximation identity, and thus $f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(K_n*f)(x)$.
\begin{align}
f(x) & = \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(K_n * f)(x) \\
& =\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \int_\mathbb{R}ng(nt)f(x-t)dt \\
& =\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} n(\int_\mathbb{R}\hat{g}(\frac{\xi}{n})e^{i2\pi tn\frac{\xi}{n}}d(\frac{\xi}{n}))f(x-t)dt\\
& = \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} (\int_\mathbb{R}
\hat{g}(\frac{\xi}{n})e^{i2\pi t\xi}f(x-t)d\xi)dt
\\
& =-\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} (\int_\mathbb{R}f(x-t)e^{-i2\pi (x-t)\xi}d(x-t)) \hat{g}(\frac{\xi}{n})e^{i2\pi x\xi}d\xi\\
& =-\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{i2\pi x\xi} \hat{f}(\xi) \hat{g}(\frac{\xi}{n})d\xi\\
\end{align}
Let $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$, we have
$$f(x) = -\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^+}
\int_\mathbb{R} e^{i2\pi x\xi} \hat{f}(\xi) \hat{g}(\delta\xi)d\xi
$$.

How do I get rid of the negative sign and let $\delta \rightarrow 0$ instead of $\delta\rightarrow 0^+$?

Comment: $\int_\mathbb{R}e^{i2\pi\xi x}\hat{g}(\delta\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)d\xi = f \ast g_{\delta}(x)$ where $g_{\delta}(x) =\frac{g(x/\delta)}{\delta}$. See also [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem#Proof) of the Fourier inversion theorem.

Comment: @user1952009 I think you're right, thank you!

Comment: @user1952009 I've tried to derive $g_\delta*f$, but I notice a quirk, as the approximation identity in the link of the proof is an even function, but I don't see how $g_\delta$ here is even. I have a negative sign somehow in my calculation. Can I simply take the absolute value of $g$ in $g_\delta$?

Comment: I don't see what you mean. You need the Fourier inversion theorem twice : for $g = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\hat{g}]$ and $f \ast g_\delta = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\hat{f}\hat{g_\delta}]$

Comment: @user1952009 I updated my derivation, please have a look. If $g$ is even then in the 2nd step I can use change of variable to make $f(x-t)$ into $f(x+t)$ then I can lose the negative sign.

Comment: You don't need $g$ even. If $\delta < 0$ then $g_{\delta}(x) =\frac{g(x/\delta)}{|\delta|}$. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem

Comment: @user1952009 I see! Thank you for your help!